# sum of a given power series

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

Given $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(n-1)(n+1)}{n!}x^n$:

a) Study it's pointwise and uniform convergence.

b) Find the value of the sum in the interval of convergence.

For a) I found that the series converges uniformly on all bounded intervals, and pointwise on all $\mathbb{R}$, but I'm stumped on b) any help is welcome.

Comment: 'Pointwise', not 'punctual'. An easy mistake to make!

Comment: edited, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

$$(n+1)(n-1)=n^2-1=n(n-1)+n-1$$

$$\implies\frac{(n+1)(n-1)}{n!}x^n=\frac{n(n-1)+n-1}{n!}x^n =x^2\cdot\frac{x^{n-2}}{(n-2)!}+x\cdot\frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}-\frac{x^n}{n!}$$

Now $\sum_{r=0}^\infty\dfrac{x^r}{r!}=e^x$

More generally for $a_0+a_1n+a_2n^2+\cdots$ in the numerator,

we can set this to $a_0+b_1n+b_2n(n-1)+\cdots$

Now set $n=1,2$ etc. to find $b_i$s in terms of $a_i$s

Comment: Shouldn't that exponent $n+2$ actually be $n-2$?

Comment: @imranfat, Rectified

Answer (score 2):

Write 
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(n-1)(n+1)}{n!}x^n
&=-1+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(n-1)n}{n!}x^n+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(n-1)}{n!}x^n\\
&=-1+x^2\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(n-1)n}{n!}x^{n-2}+x\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{n!}x^{n-1}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{n!}
\end{align}
The first series in the sum is the second derivative of the exponential, the second series is the first derivative and the last is $e^x-1$. So we get
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(n-1)(n+1)}{n!}x^n=e^x(x^2+x-1)
$$

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Still need to improve my latex